# Why TD(1) in TD(λ) is Monte Carlo update?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The `TD(λ)` update conforms to the weight of `(1-λ)`, `λ(1-λ)`, `λ^2(1-λ)` ..., but I have the confusion why when exponential goes to infinity the form turns into `λ^infinity`? Where is the `1-λ` term?

(The method is introduced intensively in many materials, but I didn't see any explanation on the last term of the weight)

Comment: Hi: that's a geometric series so, assuming $ 0<λ<1$, the finite sum of the series = $(1−λ^n)$ and the infinite sum will go to 1.0. google for "exponential smoothing" if you're interested in learning more about it. – mlofton 8 hours ago